# SQL Server - Migrate Agent Jobs to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-agent

We're in the final phase of migrating our SQL Server on VM to Azure SQL Server.  What is the most time-efficient approach to getting our existing SQL Server Agent Jobs out to Azure?  I've noticed that inside of SSMS, when connected to an Azure SQL Server, the Agent does not exist - we were aware of this before migrating, but I have yet to have found whether there is an Azure service that replaces the SQL Server Agent Jobs functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options.

If you need timed execution of some data momement, Azure Data Factory can be a good replacement.

There is also an Azure Scheduler, that is often mentioned as an alternative. However, I believe that would work better on API's than directly on a database.

I think the best option is Azure automation and create a runbook that connects to your database and performs some action.

An interesting blog that details these options in more detail can be foond at: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/05/is-sql-server-agent-missing-from-azure-sql-database/